# parts of an object vs separate objects

Tags: javascript

What's the benefit to using an object with some stuff in it, like

```
var cheese = {color: "bleu", smell: "bad", holes: false};
```

as opposed to storing separate objects for similar data, like

```
var cheeseColor = "bleu";
var cheeseSmell = "bad";
var cheeseHoles = false;
```

I know there's higher-level benefits when it comes to prototyping and constructor functions, but for a simple task, does it make a significant difference?

Comment: No, it doesn't really make much of a difference for a few variables, but  it all depends on how you intend to use that data

Comment: Depends on your actual needs.

Comment: Things I can think of: 1) Easier to pass the object as a param to a function; 2) Logical grouping

Comment: If you had 100 values instead of 3 and you needed to pass the whole bunch somewhere, then yes, there would be a major benefit to using objects.

Comment: What will you do when you have 10 different cheeses? What if you want to look for a cheese that has both a bad smell and no holes? What if you want to remove a cheese from your collection? Such things become simpler when you use OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) The biggest benefit (in my opinion) is dynamic variable handling.

Let's assume you have an object, but it's loaded through AJAX or the variables aren't made by you. Either way you don't know what's in it.

With normal variables, you're screwed. End.

But with objects, you can ask the user what he wants, and the with the `[]` operator, you can get that value:

```
var obj = {
    s: 5,
    c: "abc",
    g: /hello/g
};
function getObjectParam(name) {
    return obj[name];
}
```

Then by calling

```
getObjectParam("s")/
```

You get `5`.

This is a very simple use case. I mostly use this feature when I need to store different matrices when I use WebGL for example.

2.) Passing them

Let's say you have a library which needs something configured by the user of the lib. Instead of creating a constructor or a function, which takes in 20 arguments, you can make one which takes in an object, and you use it's values to set everything. This doesn't just make you be able to write a shorter function, but also enables the user to reuse the object if he wants to call the function again.

Comment: Another major benefit that I would add to this answer, is when you have a collection of objects. An array of objects is much easier to work with than several parallel arrays.

Comment: @Paulpro post it as a separate answer. However I look at it, this will be a collection of good answers in a matter of minutes anyways.